# How can I add ACL entry comments on a Cisco 3750?

Tags: cisco, cisco-catalyst, acl

I'm trying to find the best way to add comments into my access-lists. For the moment, the only manner I found is the following one:

```
switch#conf t
switch(config)#ip access-list extended VLAN-TEST3
switch(config-ext-nacl)#remark first remark
switch(config-ext-nacl)#10 permit ip any any
switch(config-ext-nacl)#remark second remark
switch(config-ext-nacl)#20 deny ip any any
switch(config-ext-nacl)#remark third remark
```

But by using this, I'm unable to see the comments with the command `sh ip access-list VLAN-TEST3` they appear only when I do a `sh run` (which isn't the most practical to see an ACL). I also cannot specify a number of lines for the remark and I can't modify/delete them.

What is the best way to do that? I'm using a Cisco 3750

Comment: It is a bit awkward but you could have 2 telnet sessions side by side ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cisco does not provide any other way see view access lists remarks besides viewing them from the running configuration.

The lines containing remark statements are not numbered so they are ignored when running **show ip access-list**

You can filter the running config output and display only the section regarding to access-lists like this:

```
show running-config | section ip access-list
```

Comment: That's sad, because I can't see the numbers of hits by using this way. Thanks for your answer

Comment: If the ACL is being matched you should see the numbers of hits when using show ip access-lists at the end of the line something like this: (8 matches). Also you could append the log keyword at the end of the access-list entry to display console messages when the access-list is matched

Comment: @cioby23, by adding "log" directive to the acl, ios will generate cpu irq on each mathed packet. this can dramatically reduce performance of the device. acl log must be used only in debug purposes

Comment: @cioby23 I know, but my goal was to see matches, comments and line numbers at the same time.